# Javascript autocomplete not working with a REST API array

Tags: javascript

I have an autocomplete script running on a page to allow easier searching of 400+ names, however the list of names has items added/removed from it every few weeks.

In order to make this easier to keep up with, I was wanting to call out to a list with a REST API call to return an array of these names that runs on document load.

I have a `for` loop that runs when this list is returned and selects only the name without any metadata and adds it to a second array, which the autocomplete should look at when providing completion suggestions.

I've had success with the REST API call and adding everything to a functional array, however the autocomplete **does not** return any suggestions when typing in a text box.

Note that the autocomplete code has been lifted from w3s from their [Countries of the World autocomplete example](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_autocomplete.asp), and this works with a defined array rather than the JSON array returned from the call.

```html
   <form autocomplete="off" action="/action_page.php">
   <div class="autocomplete" style="width:200px;">
    <input id="myInput" type="text" name="mySystem" placeholder="Please Enter System Name...">
   </div>
```

```js
var countries = [ ];
document.onload = getApplications();
function getApplications(){
  $.ajax({
    url: "URL/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Application List')/items?$select=Title&$top=1000",
    type: "GET",
    headers: {"accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"},
    success: function (data) {
    var appresults = data.d.results;
    for(var obj in appresults){
      var app = appresults[obj].Title;
      countries = countries.concat(app);
    }
    console.log(countries);
    }
  });
}

function autocomplete(inp, arr) {
  var currentFocus;
  inp.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
      var a, b, i, val = this.value;
      closeAllLists();
      if (!val) { return false;}
      currentFocus = -1;
      a = document.createElement("DIV");
      a.setAttribute("id", this.id + "autocomplete-list");
      a.setAttribute("class", "autocomplete-items");
      this.parentNode.appendChild(a);
      for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i].substr(0, val.length).toUpperCase() == val.toUpperCase()) {
          b = document.createElement("DIV");
          b.innerHTML = "<strong>" + arr[i].substr(0, val.length) + "</strong>";
          b.innerHTML += arr[i].substr(val.length);
          b.innerHTML += "<input type='hidden' value='" + arr[i] + "'>";
          b.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
              inp.value = this.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
              closeAllLists();
          });
          a.appendChild(b);
        }
      }
  });
  inp.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
      var x = document.getElementById(this.id + "autocomplete-list");
      if (x) x = x.getElementsByTagName("div");
      if (e.keyCode == 40) {
        currentFocus++;
        addActive(x);
      } else if (e.keyCode == 38) { //up
        currentFocus--;
        addActive(x);
      } else if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (currentFocus > -1) {
          if (x) x[currentFocus].click();
        }
      }
  });
  function addActive(x) {
    if (!x) return false;
    removeActive(x);
    if (currentFocus >= x.length) currentFocus = 0;
    if (currentFocus < 0) currentFocus = (x.length - 1);
    x[currentFocus].classList.add("autocomplete-active");
  }
  function removeActive(x) {
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      x[i].classList.remove("autocomplete-active");
    }
  }
  function closeAllLists(elmnt) {
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("autocomplete-items");
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      if (elmnt != x[i] && elmnt != inp) {
        x[i].parentNode.removeChild(x[i]);
      }
    }
  }
  document.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
      closeAllLists(e.target);
  });
}

autocomplete(document.getElementById("myInput"), countries);
```